# An Anagram Tribond: You can love it, or not

Tags: word, anagram, tribond

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #48: Unusual tag mix](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7149/fortnightly-topic-challenge-48-unusual-tag-mix)</sup>

---

Figure out what these mixed up clues are supposed to be and solve the tribond, then repeat with the results!

**Group 1:** tubings, pertain, tissued
**Group 2:** thing, roster, scepters
**Group 3:** hated, lament, manors

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Words:

   > BUSTING, PAINTER, STUDIES

   Tribond (thanks to @Bass):

   > GENRE? (my genre studies degree focused on a genre-busting genre painter) - although none of these three phrases are really familiar to me
2. Words:

   > NIGHT, RESORT, RESPECTS

   Tribond:

   > LAST (last night, as a last resort, I paid my last respects)
3. Words:

   > DEATH, MENTAL, RANSOM

   Tribond:

   > NOTE (while reading Death Note, I made a mental note to write my prisoner's ransom note)

Overall words:

> GREEN, SALT, TONE

Tribond (thanks @Graylocke):

> PEPPER (I put some salt and pepper on my green pepper bought from Tone's Pepper) - the last of these phrases is again something I'd never heard of, but this fits with the title.

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but rot13(cnvagre pbhyq nyfb or ercnvag).

Comment: Perhaps rot13(PNFR) is the one missing? with rot13(OBBX) at the end?

Comment: @Graylocke Hmm, I'm not too convinced by either of those connections.

Comment: The first tribond might be rot13("traer". Gura nantenzzvat ntnva jbhyq tvir trg "terra, fnyg, naq gbar", juvpu zvtug nyy pbaprvinoyl pbaarpg gb "syng".)

Comment: @Bass You're very close - you should be able to verify your final answer with the title, although I suppose rot13(syng) also fits the clues

Comment: @samm82 How silly of me not to check that. I guess that's what you get for anagramming way past your bedtime X-)

Comment: @Bass rot13(qbrf guvf zrna gung TERRA, FNYG naq GBAR -> CRCCRE?  V nfx orpnhfr gur ynfg frrzf gb or n cbchyne oenaq bs fcvpr... juvpu V unir arire urneq bs!)

Comment: Thanks a lot to Bass and @Graylocke (can't ping you both in one comment) - I've edited to add your contributions, and I never would've got these (at least the first one) myself.

Comment: The intended answer was rot13(rnegu - fnyg bs gur rnegu, terra rnegu, rnegu gbar - juvpu nyfb nantenzf gb urneg naq ungre sbe gur gvgyr), but that says more about the puzzle than the answer, so I'm going to accept this answer!